# Can linear model automatically identify interaction form of (x1-x2)?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

for linear regression

$y = \beta_{1} x_{1} + \beta_{2}x_{2}$

while the true model is actually $y = \beta x_{b}$ and $x_{b} =  x_{1}  -  x_{2} $

will a linear model automatically recover this relationship ?

Is there a close form proof ?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "linear model" and "recover"?  It looks like you might have $(x_1,x_2,y)$ data which you will model in the form given and you want to test the hypothesis $(\beta_1,\beta_2)=(1,-1).$  This is a standard problem and a standard $F$ test will work, but is that at all close to what "recover" might mean?

Comment: Why does your title mention "interaction"? The question body doesn't seem to ask about interaction anywhere.